# Concatenating variable with querySelector VueJS

Tags: vue.js, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate a Vue variable with an id in querySelector, and for some reason it is not targeting any element.

I am currently using:

`` document.querySelectorAll(".container:not(#`${this.id}`")); ``

`this.id` is just a string, and doesn't include the '#', which is why I am adding it to the querySelector here

What I have in the DOM is:

```
<div id="header-1" class="container">
.......
</div>
<div id="header-2" class="container">
.......
</div>
<div id="header-3" class="container">
.......
</div>
```

Comment: Are there any other elements with a class of `container`? Can you show the markup?

Comment: Yes, there are..updated my post to show what's in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using 'refs' to select a DOM directly instead of native javascript and CSS selectors.

For example `this.$refs[this.id]`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref